# python input function doesnt show actual input window

Tags: python

I just started to learn python and I am reading "automate the boring stuff" book. I wrote my first program suggested in the book that is:

```
print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?') # ask for their name
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('What is your age?') # ask for their age
myAge = input()
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

however, when I click f5, the program doesnt ask for input in the shell, it only prints this:

```
===================== RESTART: /home/user/Downloads/1.py =====================
Hello world!
What is your name?
```

I am using qubes os right now. Could it be something related to it?

Comment: What happens when you type in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, I made some small changes so it might be a little bit more obvious when/where you should input.

```
print('Hello world!')
myName = input('What is your name? ')
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
myAge = input('What is your age? ')
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

You can start typing when you see the "what is your name" query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a string in `input()`. You do not have to have separate lines of code for this. Also if you do not enter something in the console your program will block there because it expects an input from the user. As long as you do not type anything it will stay there. Your code works as is btw, but if you want to use less prints:

```
print('Hello world!')
myName = input('What is your name?')
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
myAge = input('What is your age?')
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```